# Downloading a file via cURL fails , while using chrome it works

Tags: curl

Even after going through lot of stackoverflow answers , i could not find the solution to my problem. Hence I am asking it again.

I am trying to download http://index-of.es/Magazines/hakin9/books/No.Starch.TCP.IP.Guide.Oct.2005.pdf using below command.

```
curl  -o tcp.pdf   --cookie coockie -L  http://index-of.es/Magazines/hakin9/books/No.Starch.TCP.IP.Guide.Oct.2005.pdf
--verbose
```

Output:

```
$ curl  -o tcp.pdf   --cookie coockie -L  http://index-of.es/Magazines/hakin9/books/No.Starch.TCP.IP.Guide.Oct.2005.pdf   --verbose
* Adding handle: conn: 0xb65698
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0xb65698) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to index-of.es port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 87.98.231.4...
* Connected to index-of.es (87.98.231.4) port 80 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0> GET /Magazines/hakin9/books/No.Starch.TCP.IP.Guide.Oct.2005.pdf HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: index-of.es
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: 240plan=R130020614; 240planBAK=R2339305415
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
* Replaced cookie 240plan="R130020614" for domain index-of.es, path /, expire 1500391330
< Set-Cookie: 240plan=R130020614; path=/; expires=Tue, 18-Jul-2017 15:22:10 GMT
< Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 14:20:33 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Location: http://index-of.es/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 203
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< X-IPLB-Instance: 177
<
* Ignoring the response-body
{ [data not shown]
100   203  100   203    0     0    166      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   169
* Connection #0 to host index-of.es left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://index-of.es/'
```

I suspect issue is with the  *Location: http://index-of.es/* returned in HTTP response, which is incomplete and cURL recursively tries to connect to the same Location ending up with "**curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed**"

Question:

- How chrome  is able to download the file?
     If the command i used is incomplete , what else needs to be added to the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `Curl` user-agent has been blacklisted on that server, change the `User-Agent` header :

```
curl -o tcp.pdf \
     -H "User-Agent: Mozilla" \
     -L "http://index-of.es/Magazines/hakin9/books/No.Starch.TCP.IP.Guide.Oct.2005.pdf"
```